# How to convert column to row in pyspark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I got the following result in pyspark
I used the .discribe() function

```
+------+-------+
|    _c0|   _c1|
+------+-------+
| count|2674686|
|  mean|    0.0|
|stddev|    0.0|
|   min|      0|
|   max|      0|
+------+-------+
```

i'm trying my result to converting like this

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  count|  mean| stddev|   min|   max|
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|2674686|   0.0|    0.0|      0|      0|
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

how can i solve it?
If this is hard, is it possible to change columns and rows when using the discribe() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupBy()` and `pivot` functions can be used here:

```
your_df.groupBy().pivot("_c0").agg(first('_c1')).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.pivot()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=pivot) function for that.

Example:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import first

data_frame.pivot("_c0").agg(first('_c1')).show()
```